# Stuck with a Custom Field Check box Array

Tags: array

Been stuck on this for a while now.  Haven't come across anything that has shed any light on it for me...  Pardon my ignorance... quite a newbie at this level of php.

The problem:
I am using the wp-property plugin, but need a field that can have multiple numeric values.
Using Advanced Custom Fields to set up a checkbox field that can accept multiple numeric values.
I am attempting to add this field to the wp-property search function.
I get a dropdown menu, but it is populated with lines that look like unformatted arrays.

*s:19.a:1:{i:0;s2*  and so on.  My values are in that string but I don't know what to do to single them out.

I have this in my functions.php

```
add_filter('wpp_searchable_attributes', 'add_lease_to_searchable');
 function add_lease_to_searchable($fields) {

if(is_array($fields))

array_push($fields,  'lease-space1' );


return $fields;
}
```

Which gets that dropdown to be a part of the wp-property function.  If anybody has an idea on how to extract the values... even better put one on each dropdown line, that would be amazing. Feel stuck with no light at the end of the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

It's a serialized string. Use [Unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get an array out of this. Also checkout WP's [maybe_unserialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) method.

```
<?php $string = "s:19.a:1:{i:0;s2";

//Using WP maybe_unserialize
$result1 = maybe_unserialize($string);

//Using PHP unserialize
$result2 = unserialize($string); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result1);
print_r($result2)
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

$result will hold what you want.

Comment: thanks for the incredibly quick answer.  This site is definitely a resource I am happy to have found.  But I think I am just in over my head.

Comment: You're welcome! You've found the best place to get an answer for all your WP related questions! :)
BTW, did the solution work? (I really don't understand what 'But I think I am just in over my head.' means !)

Comment: Unfortunately I am too much of a newbie to even understand how to use that method with my current code. And I am not truly confidant that I am attempting to solve the appropriate problem for my particular issue. I suppose that is what I mean by "over my head."  :(

Comment: No problem Noel! Everyone goes through that stage, even I did! :)

Comment: I may never make it to PHP ninja stage, but there are many ways to skin a cat.  I decided to go the custom taxonomy route to fix my issue... and the developer of the main plugin plans to implement taxonomy search in the somewhat near future... so I think that will work for now!  Thanks again for taking the time to respond. I will continue to visit this site as part of my learning process!  best---